# Loading data using Hive Sed command

Tags: hadoop, sed, hive

I Have my data in this format.

```
"123";"mybook1";"2002";"publisher1";
"456";"mybook2;the best seller";"2004";"publisher2";
"789";"mybook3";"2002";"publisher1";
```

the fields are enclosed in "" and are delimited by ; Also the book name may contain ';' in between.

Can you tell me how to load this data from file to hive table

the below query which i am using now obviously not working ;

```
create table books (isbn string,title string,year string,publisher string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;'
```

if possible i want the userid and year fields to be stored as Int. Please help

Also i dont want to use regexserde command.
how can i use sed command from unix to clean the data and get my output.

i tried to learn about sed command and found the replace option. So i can remove the " double quotations. But how can i handle the extra ; semi colon which comes in the middle of the data

Please help

Comment: can help in sed if i have an idea of the expected result from source (no idea of hive/hadoop protocol/structure to use). Please give a expected result sample

Answer (score 0):

I think you can preprocess with `sed` and then use the `MetadataTypedColumnsetSerDe WITH SERDEPROPERTIES`

`sed -r ':a; s/^([^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*);/\1XXXXX/g; t a; s/;/ /g; s/XXXXX/;/g' file`

This `sed` matches the quote pairs to avoid processing what is between quotes putting a placeholder for the semicolons outside of quoted text. Afterward it removes the ;'s from the book title text and replaces them w/a space and puts back the semicolons that are outside quotes.

See here for more how to load data using Hive including an example of `MetadataTypedColumnsetSerDe WITH SERDEPROPERTIES`:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/serde/README.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
create external table books (isbn int,title string,year int,publisher string)

     row format SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' WITH

     SERDEPROPERTIES ('separatorChar' = '\;' , 'quoteChar' = '\"' ) location 'S3 

    path/HDFS path for the file';
```

Comment: Some formatting and explanation would have been better.